# implementation of junit in spring batch jobs

Tags: java, junit, spring-batch

Can anyone share how to test different DAO methods in spring batch jobs using junit testing framework.How to test seperately reader, writer & processor.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer from Official Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html)